# Finding all the {param} in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

I have strings that have placeholders that are always in the form {text}

For example:

```
The {adjective} brown {animal} {action}s over the lazy {secondanimal}!
```

I would expect an array of string `["{adjective}","{animal}","{action}","{secondanimal}"]`

I'm hoping to avoid coding a solution that looks like:

```
Look for '{' then look for '}' then take substring.
```

What might be a more straightforward way with a regex or LINQ? I noticed the Split method but I have more than just a delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `{param}` elements only contain word characters I would use `{[\w]+}` to match them.

```
string input = "The {adjective} brown {animal} {action}s over the lazy {secondanimal}!";
string[] result = Regex.Matches(input, @"{[\w]+}").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

The definition of your `{param}` is a bit broad. For this example you could also use `{[a-z]+}`.

Note, this approach doesn't work for nested `{param}`.